# 2020 chrys Pacifica horn won’t blow; Adaptive Cruise cntrl and More won’t work after minor bump to front left corner of bumper

Tags: electrical, sensor, chrysler, horn, pacifica

Had minor bump to the left corner of the front bumper.  NOw the horn won’t blow; the ACC Adaptive Cruise Contl; Forward Collision Warning won’t work. Engine runs hot at 240 degrees instead of normal 190 - 200.
I suspect radiator fans may not be turning on.
All this after a minor bump to the left corner of front bumper where there is mounted one of those small radar sensors mounted in the bumper…about the size of a quarter. Tried shut  off and restart made no difference. Radar sensor looks okay; not even scratched.
Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Adaptive Cruise and Forward Collision Warning both rely on the radar system. The sensors are quite sensitive. The "minor bump" could easily either break one of the sensors or make it lose calibration. Either way, that portion of what your issues are will need to go to a mechanic which can diagnose, fix, and recalibrate the system.